# SSMS 2016 Query Store: Missing Index Details error: DocumentFrame (SQLEditors)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

Each time I try and view missing index details in Query store I get the following error:

> DocumentFrame (SQLEditors)
>
> Program Location:    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ShowPlan.ShowPlanControl.OnMissingIndexDetails(Object
>   sender, EventArgs a)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.MenuCommand.Invoke()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ShowPlan.ShowPlanControl.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid&
>   guidGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdExcept, IntPtr vIn, IntPtr vOut)

Is anybody else experiencing this? Is this something I can fix or is it a bug?

SSMS version 13.0.16106.4

It's a bit frustrating as I can't view the end of the create index recommendation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is happening to me from Query Store query plan screens on SSMS 13.0.16106.4 as well.

Workaround that I found, until they fix it:

- Press "New Query" button for a blank new tab
- Switch back to the Query Store tab and right-click, select "Missing Index Details" again
- It'll open up the missing index details in a third tab

When you look at another, you may have to repeat the steps, even if you still have the blank tab open.

Comment: This should be best answer

Comment: Thank you for this workaround.  Hard to believe that we're about to celebrate this fix's 2nd Birthday and NO FIX from Microsoft yet.

Answer (score 1):

Kendra Little has discussed some of the problems at: (Link corrected)

[SSMS 2016 Query Store Missing Index Details Error Document Frame Sqleditors](https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/03/07/sql-server-2016-rc0-fixes-index-usage-stats-bug-missing-indexes-still-broken/)

She also has created a link to the [Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2446044). You can go there a vote it up, if you wish.

Also the **Quick Rundown** at the bottom includes comments on which behaviors you can expect. Since you are running SQL Server 2016, note:

**SQL Server 2016** Reset on database offline/restart.

- Reset on any index drop/disable/create on that table.
- Reset on database offline/restart.
- **Reset on ALTER INDEX REBUILD of any index on the table.**

So perhaps you can work around the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi. Yes I found Kendras website and it mentioned there was an issue. (Pls note your link doesn't work). But not steps to address it. I will upvote on connect. cheers.

Comment: Actually to clarify. Kendras connect post talks about clearing out missing index data whereas my issue is with being able to view the in SSMS. I can see most of the missing index recommendation, it so it must be there somewhere, I just can't open it.